# shell script is not failing with error scenario happening

Tags: bash, shell

Why is the script not failing when the merge marketable count is clearly less than the marketable count. I should be seeing the error array output and the exit status working below

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sample local values
merge_marketable_count=0
marketable_count=200
countDifference=95/100  # This still assigns the string "95/100" to countDifference. 

merge_opt_out_count=50
opt_out_count=60

total_merge_count=500
total_count=550

errorArray=()

if [ "$merge_marketable_count" -lt "$(( marketable_count * ${countDifference} ))" ]; then
  marketable_message="The total Marketable counts within our EMU table is greater than 5%, merge=$merge_marketable_count, view=$marketable_count and CountDiffUsed=${countDifference}"
  echo $marketable_message
  errorArray+=("$marketable_message")
fi


if [ ${#errorArray[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "error array"
  echo "${#errorArray[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
```

i ran the script locally and expected an error to trigger

Comment: A useful utility when debugging shell scripts is to add "set -x" to the top of the script. This will cause bash to output the commands after substitution, but before executing them. You can then compare this to your expectations to see where things go wrong.

Comment: Get here "error array 3". What output do you expect ?

Comment: bash doesn't do floating point math for starters.

Comment: Even if it did multiplying a variable holding "200" by one holding "95/100" is unlikely to do what you want. You'd need a language that supports rational numbers, like scheme, for that to work without extra steps.

Comment: if it's installed, you can use `bc` to handle the floating point stuff, (`[ 0 -lt $(bc -e 200*.95) ]`.).  The `-lt` won't consider the floating point but that should be fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use set -e at the beginning. It will exit in fail condition.